# JsonSerializationException while using PopulateObject function from Newtonsoft

Tags: c#, json, exception, json.net

Coding in C#, I am blocked on a silly JSON deserialization and hoping your expert eyes will find what I'm missing.

I am trying to extract the following JSON file:

```json
{
  "Document": 
  {
    "Version": "1.0.0",
    "LastUpdate": "10.08.2020",
    "Description": "This document enumarates manufactuer capabilities",
    "Id": ""
  },
  "Capacities": [
    {
      "Id": 0,
      "Description": "",
      "Enable": true,
      "RelativePath": "Company1\\manifest.json"
    },
    {
      "Id": 1,
      "Description": "",
      "Enable": true,
      "RelativePath": "Company2\\manifest.json"
    }
  ]
}
```

The **ManifestDescriptor class** should self-extract (and store) JSON data through its constructor call. The implementation is as follow:

```cs
using JsonTools;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using Serilog;
using SessionService;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

namespace BaseService.Manifest
{
    public class ManifestDescriptor : JObject
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Contains Json document descriptor data
        /// </summary>
        private DocSection _document;

        private List<Capacity> _capacity;

        /// <summary>
        /// Contains Json document descriptor data
        /// </summary>
        [JsonProperty("Document")]
        public DocSection Document
        {
            get => _document;
            set
            {
                if (value != _document)
                {
                    _document = value;
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Contains document capacities
        /// </summary>
        [JsonProperty("Capacities")]
        public List<Capacity> Capacities
        {
            get => _capacity;
            internal set
            {
                if (value != _capacity)
                {
                    _capacity = value;
                }
            }
        }

        public ManifestDescriptor(string absolutePath)
        {
            string l_rawJson = string.Empty;

            if (File.Exists(absolutePath))
            {
                _fileInfo = new FileInfo(absolutePath);

                if (!JsonParser.LoadJsonFile(absolutePath, ref l_rawJson))
                {
                    Log.Error("Could not extract Json file data.");
                    return;
                }

                //  Populate current class with manifest data
                JsonConvert.PopulateObject(l_rawJson, this);
            }
            else Log.Warning("Given manifest file do not exist: \n\r {0}", absolutePath);
        }
    }
}
```

ManifestDescriptor contains a **Document** property implemented as follow:

```cs
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

namespace BaseService.Manifest
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Class container giving Json document version & its utility
    /// </summary>
    public class DocSection
    {
        private Version _version;

        private DateTime _lastUpdate;

        private string _description;

        private string _id;

        private string _class;

        /// <summary>
        /// Contains document version
        /// </summary>
        [JsonProperty("Version")]
        public Version Version
        {
            get => _version;
            internal set
            {
                if (value != _version)
                {
                    _version = value;
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Contains last update document version
        /// </summary>
        [JsonProperty("LastUpdate")]
        public DateTime LastUpdate
        {
            get => _lastUpdate;
            internal set
            {
                if(value != _lastUpdate)
                {
                    _lastUpdate = value;
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Contains document description
        /// </summary>
        [JsonProperty("Description")]
        public string Description
        {
            get => _description;
            internal set
            {
                if(value != _description)
                {
                    _description = value;
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Contains document ID
        /// </summary>
        [JsonProperty("Id")]
        public string Id
        {
            get => _id;
            internal set
            {
                if (value != _id)
                {
                    _id = value;
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Object class type to instanciate regarding capacity data of the document
        /// </summary>
        [JsonIgnore]
        [JsonProperty("Class")]
        public string Class
        {
            get => _class;
            internal set
            {
                if(value != _class)
                {
                    _class = value;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However when reaching the line `JsonConvert.PopulateObject(l_rawJson, this);` called in ManifestDescriptor class constructor, I am reaching the following execption:

> Cannot populate JSON object onto type
> 'BaseService.Manifest.ManifestDescriptor'. Path 'Document', line 2,
> position 13."

**May you have an idea of the issue?**

Thanks for your attention,

Comment: Check the `Version` property, [`Version` constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.version.-ctor?view=netcore-3.1#System_Version__ctor_System_String_), accepting string, requires it in format of `x.x.x.x`, with 4 digits, bot the 3

Comment: Remove `JsonConvert.PopulateObject(l_rawJson, this);` from constructor do somewhere else. It should solve your problem.

Comment: Would this work for your case: https://dotnetfiddle.net/IVJXnM. Also during parsing your posted `JSON` string, I was receiving an error: `Run-time exception (line 11): Bad JSON escape sequence: \m. Path 'Capacities[0].RelativePath', line 1, position 211.`. This is because of your `//` characters in the string. I solved it by simply double escape all the `\`

Comment: Thanks @RahulSharma, your code did help in caching the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your attention. Combined comments help me to find out the issue. Coming back from *@Rahul Sharma* code answer and drawing back towards my original code, I could detect the two following issues:

1. **Setter should not be declared as `internal`** otherwise `JsonConvert.PopulateObject(...)` function will end with a nullable object.
2. I've set `ManifestDescriptor` class as child of `Jobject`. **Removing the parent seems to resolve the raised exception I get.**

The working code is then:

**ManifestDescriptor class**:

```
 public class ManifestDescriptor
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Manifest file information field
        /// </summary>
        private FileInfo _fileInfo;

        /// <summary>
        /// Contains Json document descriptor data
        /// </summary>
        private DocSection _document;

        private List<Capacity> _capacity;

        /// <summary>
        /// Manifest file information
        /// </summary>
        public FileInfo FileInfo
        {
            get => _fileInfo;
            set
            {
                if(value != _fileInfo)
                    _fileInfo = value;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Contains Json document descriptor data
        /// </summary>
        [JsonProperty("Document")]
        public DocSection Document
        {
            get => _document;
            set
            {
                if (value != _document)
                {
                    _document = value;
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Contains document capacities
        /// </summary>
        [JsonProperty("Capacities")]
        public List<Capacity> Capacities
        {
            get => _capacity;
            internal set
            {
                if (value != _capacity)
                {
                    _capacity = value;
                }
            }
        }

        public ManifestDescriptor(string absolutePath)
        {
            string l_rawJson = string.Empty;

            if (File.Exists(absolutePath))
            {
                _fileInfo = new FileInfo(absolutePath);

                if (!JsonParser.LoadJsonFile(absolutePath, ref l_rawJson))
                {
                    Log.Error("Could not extract Json file data.");
                    return;
                }

                //  Populate current class with manifest data
                JsonConvert.PopulateObject(l_rawJson, this);
            }
            else Log.Warning("Given manifest file do not exist: \n\r {0}", absolutePath);
        }
    }
```

**DocSection class (Document property)**:

```
/// <summary>
/// Class container giving Json document version & its utility
/// </summary>
public class DocSection
{
    private Version _version;

    private DateTime _lastUpdate;

    private string _description;

    private string _id;

    private string _class;

    /// <summary>
    /// Contains document version
    /// </summary>
    [JsonProperty("Version")]
    public Version Version
    {
        get => _version;
        set
        {
            if (value != _version)
            {
                _version = value;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Contains last update document version
    /// </summary>
    [JsonProperty("LastUpdate")]
    public DateTime LastUpdate
    {
        get => _lastUpdate;
        set
        {
            if(value != _lastUpdate)
            {
                _lastUpdate = value;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Contains document description
    /// </summary>
    [JsonProperty("Description")]
    public string Description
    {
        get => _description;
        set
        {
            if(value != _description)
            {
                _description = value;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Contains document ID
    /// </summary>
    [JsonProperty("Id")]
    public string Id
    {
        get => _id;
        internal set
        {
            if (value != _id)
            {
                _id = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As per @SelimYildiz, you really need to separate the population of objetc outside of the object you are trying to serialize.

If your intention is to serialize your `ManifestDescriptor` without knowing the process of it all you need is to past your json. Then you can create a wrapper class that will do the thing.

What is your intention of making the `ManifestDescriptor` inherit a `JObject`?

This might give you a hint, for this sample demo I didn't inherit the `JObject` and instead of `JsonConvert.PopulateObject` I used `JsonConvert.Deserialized`.

Wrapper Class

```
public class ParserWrapper<T>
    where T : new()
{
    private FileInfo _fileInfo;

    public T ParsedObject { get; set; }

    public ParserWrapper(string absolutePath)
    {
        string l_rawJson = string.Empty;

        if (File.Exists(absolutePath))
        {
            _fileInfo = new FileInfo(absolutePath);

            if (!JsonParser.LoadJsonFile(absolutePath, ref l_rawJson))
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("Could not extract Json file data.");
                return;
            }

            //  Populate current class with manifest data
            ParsedObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(l_rawJson);
        }
        else System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("Given manifest file do not exist: \n\r {0}", absolutePath);
    }
}
```

ManifestorDescriptor

```
public class ManifestDescriptor
{
    private DocSection _document;

    private List<Capacity> _capacity;

    [JsonProperty("Document")]
    public DocSection Document
    {
        get => _document;
        set
        {
            if (value != _document)
            {
                _document = value;
            }
        }
    }

    [JsonProperty("Capacities")]
    public List<Capacity> Capacities
    {
        get => _capacity;
        internal set
        {
            if (value != _capacity)
            {
                _capacity = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Implementation

```
var obj = new ParserWrapper<ManifestDescriptor>("json1.json");
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: Hi @tontonsevilla, I was writing the answer while you've posted yours. Your code seems really interrrested. **The issue was indeed to inherit from JObject**. I thought I had to inherit from to perform Json serialization/ desarialization... but that's a mistake from my side.

**However, what is the reason I should *really need to separate the population of objetc outside of the object you are trying to serialize* ?**